# Does update globally installed angular-cli have side effects on projects with older version

Tags: angular-cli

The Angular/cli will be installed globally, but projects created with it, will contain also a devDependency on it.
Assume I have some release branch of some project which uses a certain version of Angular/cli, will the project be effected when I update the globally installed Angular/cli to the latest version?
Or will the released project keep using its own specified devDependency version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the working directory from where you call `npm` and `ng`. The @angular/cli libraries are installed in the project's local npm_modules. If you call `npm` or `ng` from the project's root folder, the local version will be found first. If you call from some other place, the globally installed libraries will be found.

So you may have a local version in your project different from the global one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it. I'm indeed calling them normally form the project's root folder. So older release branches will not be effect by a newer global version.